# Imagemagick convert incorrectly sizes landscape pdfs

Tags: pdf, conversion, imagemagick

When I run

```
convert example.pdf example.png
```

I get a png image, but the image in the pdf is off-center and too small. How do I convert so that the png image is the right size and takes the whole page?

Actually, this conversion is an automatic feature of an Elog that I use. If I do end up altering the call to convert, I need to do it programatically so the image orientation is detected and the correct options applied.

When doing this with portrait-oriented images, it works fine.

example.pdf:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8k2odc384tixzb/example.pdf

example.png:
[image: ExamplePNG]

Comment: Sorry, I can't post the images directly, until I have 10 rep, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `-trim` option:

```
     -trim                trim image edges
```

You can use it like this:

```
convert -trim -background black example.pdf example.png
```

To get this image:

[image]

The image above takes up the whole page, save it and open it locally to see it correctly.

Comment: Also the `-density` option for resolution. Might also require repage after trimming.

Comment: Yep, that works. Any idea why imagemagick does the conversion so poorly by default?